# Default Constructor in the Subclass Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

I am creating a class `ExtendBigInt` that extends the BigInteger class and needs to able to set the default value to 0. However, since BigInteger cannot be edited, how do I create a no parameter constructor in the child class? When I try to create a constructor of the child class with no parameter, it throws this error `Implicit super constructor BigInteger() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ExtendBigInt extends BigInteger{


    public ExtendBigInt() {

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //BigInteger one = new BigInteger("0");
         //BigInteger two = new BigInteger("1111111111111111111111");
         //BigInteger result = one.subtract(two);
         //System.out.println(one); // -1111111111110987654322
         //double down = result.doubleValue(); // returns a double 
         //System.out.println(down); // -1.1111111111109876E21
         //System.out.println(one.toString()); // 123456789
         //System.out.println(result.subtract(two)); // -2222222222222098765433
         //System.out.println(one.multiply(two)); // 137174209999999999999986282579
         //System.out.println(result.multiply(result).multiply(result).multiply(result));
         // 1524157902758048400486511315461168814591948287890638869506006559674928884826743139856
         //System.out.println(BigInteger.ONE); // Commonly used BigInteger("1") 

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `super(0);` in the constructor?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
public ExtendBigInt() {
    super("0");
}
```

There isn't an empty constructor in `BigInteger`, thus you get that error

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I couldn't grasp this concept when I was actually trying it!

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is calling `super(0)`, as @ShashwatKanna already pointed out.

But maybe another solution might solve your problem better: not to extend `BigInteger`.

From your example I don't see a reason why your class should want to extend `BigInteger`. You can use `BigInteger` arithmetic in any class you like, without a need to extend `BigInteger`, like:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ExtendBigInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         BigInteger one = new BigInteger("0");
         BigInteger two = new BigInteger("1111111111111111111111");
         BigInteger result = one.subtract(two);
         System.out.println(one);
         double down = result.doubleValue();
         System.out.println(down);
         System.out.println(one.toString());
         System.out.println(result.subtract(two));-2222222222222098765433
         System.out.println(one.multiply(two));
         System.out.println(result.multiply(result).multiply(result).multiply(result));

         System.out.println(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
}
```

There's no use for your `public ExtendBigInt() { ... }` constructor, as there's no `new ExtendBigInt(...)` call in your code.

And if you really want to extend `BigInteger`, then I don't see a valid use case for only a no-args constructor:

- Extending `BigInteger` means to create objects that are integers of unlimited size (`BigInteger`s) with some additional properties (fields, methods, behaviour, ...). The no-args constructor can only create a constant value, probably 0, which you can't change later, so it only creates a "ExtendBigZero".
- You should at least add a `public ExtendBigInt(String digits) { ... }` constructor or something similar that allows you to create instances with values different from zero.
- You should have some additional fields or methods  (not static) in your class so an `ExtendBigInt` is really a different thing than a `BigInteger` - if an `ExtendBigInt` behaves exactly the same as a `BigInteger`, why have a different class?